# Are there examples of publications using DFT instead of HF as a coupled-cluster reference?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, density-functional-theory, ab-initio

I have been searching for a while, and only managed to find an article by M. Saitow,<sup>[1]</sup> where CAM-B3LYP orbitals are used. I was wondering if this has been done elsewhere.

It was recommended to me by a colleague, and it is an easy enough thing in practice, but I wanted to find some stronger motivation in order to be able to trust the results.

#### References:

1. Saitow, M.; Becker, U.; Riplinger, C.; Valeev, E. F.; Neese, F. A new near-linear scaling, efficient and accurate, open-shell domain-based local pair natural orbital coupled cluster singles and doubles theory. *J. Chem. Phys.* **2017,** *146* (16), 164105. [DOI: 10.1063/1.4981521](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4981521).

Comment: I remember that Head-Gordon used DFT orbitals for [MP2 and MP3](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00986) and it looks like it's been used for [CCSD(T) vibrations](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00746)